# How to color code cells with condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have data in the excel like below

```
  A   B     C     D
sam  9.8    sam   1
kev  0.1    kev   0.1
ashl 2      ashl  2
kris 5.5    kris  3
```

I'm trying to color code B,D if for eg:A1=C1 and B1=D1 then color B1,D1 green else orange.I tried below formula to get 0 or 1 depends on true or false in column E. How do i proceed color code in VBA because my range will change dynamically

```
=IF(AND(A1=D1,B1=E1),0,1)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post this on [su]

Comment: Use a conditional formatting rule `=AND($A1=$D1, $B1=$E1)` , select the applied range as `A1:D*insert number here*`.

Comment: @TimWilkinson I was going to suggest something similar, but is this possible with Excel 2010, as OP has listed this in the tags? This [doc](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) says this feature is only available in Excel 2013/16.

Comment: @Clusks yes it works in 2010, also works in 2007. Never owned 2003 to test.

Comment: @Tim `A1:D*insert number here*` D range will change dynamic here.How do i specify that number

Comment: @sam its only conditional formatting so make `*insert number here*` something along the lines of 1048576

Comment: Be wary when you change a range of a conditional formatting excel sometimes likes to mess with your formula, so you often have write the formula, set the range, go fix the formula, never worked out why it does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Alt+F11. This brings you to where you want to put your VBA code. Press Insert, then insert a Module. Open the module.

Type this:

```
Option Explicit 'not necessary but good practice to make sure you define all variables

Public Sub highlightCells()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lastrow As Long

    'finds your last row, helps keep it dynamic
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If (Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value) And (Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value) Then
            Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(178, 255, 102) 'green
            Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(178, 255, 102)
        Else
            Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 178, 102) 'orange
            Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 178, 102)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Then, while your cursor is anywhere between "Public Sub" and "End Sub" press F5. This will run the code so you can make sure it's what you're looking for. Next, I will explain how to make it a button on your sheet...

Go to your excel spreadsheet. In the Developer tab, go to insert, under Active X Click CommandButton. Draw the CommandButton wherever you want it on your sheet.  Double click the button you just drew. Inside the code that appears automatically, type

```
Module1.highlightCells
```

Go back to your Excel sheet, in the Developer tab, Click "Design Mode". This will enable/disable design mode, allowing you to use your button which should work now.

Also, keep in mind that I skipped over certain things that are considered "good practice", like renaming objects and such. If you need help with that too please let me know. One more thing, I chose the type of green and orange we used myself but if you'd like to change it you can use the RGB (Red, Green, Blue) codes found here: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the normal conditional formula itself. Perform the following steps.

1. Click on D, which selects column D
2. Then Click on B, which selects column B.
3. Ensure that the current cell or Default is B1
4. Click on Conditional formatting options, in that select "Manage Rules"
5. In Conditional formatting rule manage window, click on New Rule button
6. In the new formatting Rule window. select Use a formula to determine which cells to format
7. Enter =OR($D1<>$B1,$A1<>$C1) in the Format values where this formula is true edit box
8. Select the Orange color and click ok
9. Do the step through 5 through 8 using the =AND($D1=$B1,$A1=$C1) formula and the Green color.
10. Step 3 is critical, once you ensure that will be considered as relative cell and it will be applicable to all cells.